# SQL Trigger on Insert into one table, copy into another multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have 2 tables setup in my database - fitness_report and result.

fitness_report has the following columns (in order):

```
report_id, test_period, test_date, student_id
```

results has the following columns (in order):

```
test_id, student_id, report_id, score
```

What I need to happen is when a new row is created on table fitness_report, 
entries are made to the results table as follows, where student_id and report_id are copied from the new row made on fitness_report:

```
1, student_id, report_id, null
2, student_id, report_id, null
3, student_id, report_id, null
4, student_id, report_id, null
5, student_id, report_id, null
6, student_id, report_id, null
```

Could you please suggest the best way to go about doing this.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a trigger on `INSERT` event. Check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html).

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger AFTER INSERT ON fitness_report 
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO results SET student_id = NEW.student_id, report_id=NEW.report_id;  
  END;
```

Comment: That'll insert the student_id and report_id into the results table, but how do i insert the static data as well? (test_id and score)?

Comment: Would this work:

CREATE TRIGGER newReport AFTER INSERT ON fitness_report 
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 INSERT INTO results(1, NEW.student_id, NEW.report_id, null);
 INSERT INTO results(2, NEW.student_id, NEW.report_id, null);
 INSERT INTO results(3, NEW.student_id, NEW.report_id, null);
 INSERT INTO results(4, NEW.student_id, NEW.report_id, null);
 INSERT INTO results(5, NEW.student_id, NEW.report_id, null);
  END;

Comment: Try `INSERT INTO results SET student_id = NEW.student_id, report_id=NEW.report_id, score=null;`. You can repeat the `INSERT` statement to insert multiple records.

Comment: I'm getting the following error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: Let me know if it works. I'll update the answer acordingly. Although AFTER INSERT is preferred. You can check for syntax in documentation.